# Tiempo dedicado en Redmine

Tags: .net

Hola a los usuarios de Redmine. Alguno sabe si existe alguna forma de no ingresar manualmente el tiempo dedicado. O sea, posibilidad de agregar algún botón "iniciar tarea" y luego el sistema calcule automáticamente el tiempo dedicado a la misma hasta que ésta sea resuelta y no sea un dato que deba ingresarse manualmente.  Y además de iniciar tarea, se pueda pausar para evitar que el tiempo siga corriendo. 
Espero se entienda. Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Supongo que pusiste .net como etiqueta porque no hay una etiqueta redmine no? Mira tambien por favor [ask]. Buscate algun plugin o algo para hacer eso?

Comment: Hola @danissr, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Redmine tiene una [API para desarrolladores](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api) que permite leer los datos (no sé si escribir también, no la he usado antes). Deberías investigar un poco por ese lado y ver si te sirve, y entonces hacer una pregunta más concreta. Tal y como está ahora, es demasiado amplia. Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Hola, gracias por sus respuestas.  Estuve leyendo a cerca de la API y serviría para lo que estaba necesitando.  Además encontré una herramienta que ya está hecha y la comparto: "Redmine Time Tracker", es una extensión para el navegador.  Podes loguearte y luego elegir entre tus tareas para dar inicio a un timer que controla el tiempo que le dedicas a dicha tarea, además podes usar Pomodoro.  Saludos!